# Is it possible to loop tests in TestCafe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm trying to loop the tests with a for clause because I want to simply get data from JSON external file (who has many Nodes and SubNodes).
I get the "No tests to run" error.
I use TestCafe 1.6.0 and TestCafe Studio 1.1.0.

Here some sample code:

```
import { t } from 'testcafe';
import {Selector} from 'testcafe';
import {Role} from 'testcafe';
import {helperFunc1, helperFunc2} from '../helper.js';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const rawdata = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../data.json"));
var data = JSON.parse(rawdata);

fixture `Test`
    .page `http://www.testpage.com`
    .beforeEach(t => t.resizeWindow(1920, 1080))

for(var i = 0; i < data.jsonNode[i].length; i++)
{
    test(`Test - 1`, async t => {await helperFunc1(data.jsonNode[i]); 

    test(`Test - 2`, async t => {await helperFunc2(data.jsonNode[i], "All", "#HASH"); });
}
```

data.JSON Example

```
{
"jsonNode": [
        {

                "test1": "A",
                "test2": "101",
                "test3": "2",
                "test4": "4"
        },
        {

                "test1": "B",
                "test2": "102",
                "test3": "3",
                "test4": "5"
        }],

"jsonNode1": [
        {

                "test10": "A",
                "test11": "101",
                "test12": "2",
                "test13": "4"
        },
        {

                "test10": "B",
                "test11": "102",
                "test12": "3",
                "test13": "5"
        }]
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `for-loop` look like this? `for(var i = 0; i < data.jsonNode.length; i++)` instead of this: `for(var i = 0; i < data.jsonNode[i].length; i++)`? Note the break condition is not refferring to `jsonNode[i].length` but to `jsonNode.length`

Comment: No, because I want to iterate through the jsonNode node in the JSON file and not in the entire file. so the length refers to the JSON node.

Comment: It would be easier if you post a couple of *nodes* from `data.json`

Comment: updated with some json code from data.json, not the real one, but the structure is the same.

Comment: You mean `for(var i = 0; i < data[ "jsonNode" + i].length; i++)` ?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer or even `for(var i = 0; i < data[ "jsonNode" + (i === 0 ? '' : i)].length; i++)` as far as I can see

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek ;-) of cause you're right, I'm the blind man.

Comment: I want to iterate only in the subnodes of the 'jsonNode' Node, maybe posting the 'jsonNode1' makes some confusion in the post

Comment: The subnodes of the `jsonNode` node are not iterable. Those are objects, not arrays. What exactly do you want to achieve? What type of argument does the `helperFunc` accept?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I think your first comment is the solution. As I understand, the OP want's to iterate over the array that's attached to `jsonNode`. So the upper exclusive limit is  `jsonNode.length` but not `jsonNode[i].length`.

Comment: I want to execute the tests in the loop  for each subNodes (accessing the correct properties). helperFunc accept one argument: the correct Subnode of JsonNode defined by the index 'i'. This method works only executing a single test (without the for loop) and using the for loop inside my function that do the action in my page.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve ;P Pure shot: change `var i` to `let i` in your `for-loop`. You are using `async` functions, maybe that's the case

Comment: I made it working using let i instead var i.

Answer (score 1):

looping tests is definitely possible with TestCafé, with a construction quite close to the one you describe.

Given the following JSON file, stored in "dataset.json" :

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "MyFirstNode",
            "foo": "bar1"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "MySecondNode",
            "foo": "bar2"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "MyThirdNode",
            "foo": "bar3"
        },
    ]
}
```

TestCafé can loop on 'nodes' with the following implementation:

```
// JSON dataSet containing array on which we will loop the tests 
const dataSet = require( __dirname + 'dataset.json' );

fixture('MyLoopingTests')
    .page('http://www.example.com');

// Getting the 'nodes' as a const for readability purpose 
const nodes = dataSet.nodes; 

nodes.forEach((nodes) => {
    test(`Run the tests for "${node.name}"`, async t => {

            // My test details for 'node'
    });
})
```

resulting in the following output:

```
MyLoopingTests
✓ Run the tests for "MyFirstNode"
✓ Run the tests for "MySecondNode"
✓ Run the tests for "MyThirdNode"
```

Comment: but this reloads the fixture every time so the values in other inputs are being cleared; is there a way to loop through inside a single test